# How get mixed content XML/HTM?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a mixed content like this:

```
    <root>
    <element1>
      text
    </element1>
      <element2>
        <text>A <i>b</i></text>
      </element2>
    </root>
```

[I tried this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666904/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-mixed-text-and-element-markup-in-xml) to obtain the whole content with including the sub nodes with the tag "`<i>`", but in these two Examples I use Path to XML:

```
$reader->XML($xml); or 
$dom->loadXML($xml); $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

and obtaining whole content of the XML. 
**How can I obtain just the result text "A b"?**

Answer (score 0):

Should be used:

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
 '//*|//text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]'
);
```

Absolute pathway to the source.